# How do I transmit multiple messages simultaneously during simulation in omnett++

Tags: c++, oop, omnet++

I want to have multiple messages move in the simulation at the same time.

My network has multiple active messages but only one message moves at any given time. The other messages seem to pause and wait until none are moving before they move. They take turns moving as if they are in a queue.

Is there any way to have all my messages transmit/move simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between concurrently in **animation time** or concurrently in **simulation time**. Check the simulation time value in the upper right corner. Even if messages are animated sequentially the simulation time may or may not advance, so effectively those messages are sent in parallel if the simulation time did not advance. So I believe, those messages are indeed transmitted concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

In Qtenv messages in broadcast transmission (i.e. one to many) may be moved simultaneously. However, there is no way to move regular messages concurrently.